# IPhone CoreData: How should I relate many child entities to their parents

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

I am trying to import data from a database that uses primary key / foreign key relations to a core data database in Xcode.

I have code that creates hundreds of child entities in a managed object context:

Each child has an ID that corresponds to a parent.

```
child1    parentID = 3
child2    parentID = 17
child3    parentID = 17
...
childn    parentID = 5
```

I now need to relate each child to its parent.  The parents are all stored in persistent memory.

My first thought was to preform a fetch for each child to get its parent.  However, I think this would be slow.

Am I correct? How should I do this instead?

Comment: Im going to try individual fetch requests and set
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
to reduce the overhead of loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking at a few examples and have decided that the best approach would be the following

1) Fetch all the parents

2) Transfer them into a dictionary with their parentID as the key

Then for each child, look up its parent in the dictionary, then relate them together.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you modeling this parent-child relationship using an attribute in the child entity?
You should model this using a to-many relationship from the parent entity to the child entity, and a to-one inverse relationship from the child to the parent entity. Set on delete cascade on the to-many relationship and nullify on the to-one relationship.

Then, once you have a child object you simply use the to-one relationship to the parent entity to access the child's parent.

Comment: Yes this is how it is modelled.  Unfortunately I am getting the data from a external database, that uses the primary key/forign key design.  I need to bridge the relationship once, then I can forget the parentID.

Comment: "you simply use the to-one relationship to the parent entity to access the child's parent"  A code example would be most helpful for those of us new to core data.

Comment: OK... now I know what you mean (and it is simple - once you wrap your head around core data).  To access the parent entity you use child.RelationshipToParent.attributeName.  So NSLOG(@"this is the parent name %@", child.RelationshipToParent.parentName); works.